# Rotation problem when using bezier interpolation

Tags: animation, bezier-curves, interpolation

I have built an helicopter and I rotated its propeller, when I used linear curve interpolation everything went fine. However, when I changed the interpolation to bezier it keeps rotating back and forth. I am using Blender 2.91.2.

Comment: The rotor would only need bezier, when starting and stopping, going from zero to full speed, and back to stillness. Once it reaches a certain RPMs, the rotation should be the linear, sustaining the same speed. Also keep in mind that there is a point where, depending on the frame rate, the rotation seems to go backwards, not because it is actually going backwards, but because of how we perceive motion. On some films you will see the wagon wheels running backwards or the tires of cars or trains as well. See: https://io9.gizmodo.com/why-do-wheels-sometimes-appear-to-spin-backwards-1593807400

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, I do not think this is the problem, otherwise, when I changed to linear interpolation I would see the "whell effect", but that not happens.  What is important to mention though is that if I set the amount of rotation not too high this does not happen, no more than 4000, it works fine, if more than that, it start fast and decrease the speed a lot then start increase again. But again, this does not happen in linear interpolation.